What does "fuss" mean in "have you all been fussing"?
This context comes from the book "To Kill a Mocking Bird" by Harper Lee.
The setting of the book is in the southern U.S. which could be important for this question.
It's the part of the book in which a young girl is mad at her relative that she's visiting during Christmas time. She is chasing him around a house telling him to take back something that he said about her father.
Francis was running away from Jean and locked himself in the kitchen to avoid her. Suddenly their aunt is getting involved in the situation.
Francis came to the door and yelled, “Grandma, she’s got me in here and she won’t let me out!”
“What is all this, Jean Louise?”
I looked up at Aunt Alexandra. “I haven’t got him in there, Aunty, I ain’t holdin‘ him”
“Yes she is,” shouted Francis, “she won’t let me out!”
“Have you all been fussing?”
Is this the correct definition for "fussing" in this case?
(intransitive, US, especially of babies) To cry or be ill-humoured.(Wictionary)
P.S. According to my Polish dictionary the word "fuss" can mean to "quarrel" but any evidence for this word, in any English dictionaries, to mean "quarrel" is pointing to the noun usage and not the verb.

It's one of several similar uses throughout the book. I'm not familiar with this usage, but the meaning seems clear.

It's southern for fighting verbally.

It is dialectal and means quarreling, bickering, squabbling. It’s similar in meaning to making a fuss, when that’s used to mean grousing or complaining. (Note that make a fuss can also mean go to a great deal of trouble on someone’s behalf, as in, “Just a glass of water would be fine for me. I would hate to inconvenience you, so please don’t make a fuss on my account.”

The baby is fussing, in not dialectal, though.

This use of fuss is dialect.  To Kill a Mockingbird is full of non-standard English, meant to convey the way people in 1930s Alabama spoke.  For example, on the same page as your quote (in the version I'm looking at) I can find these non-standard words:

agin - dialectical spelling/pronunciation of again
ain't - am not
nome - contraction of no ma'am

In this context, fussing seems mean fighting.  We can find other examples of this usage in To Kill a Mockingbird.  This one makes the meaning quite clear:

Jem got up and padded across the rug. He motioned me to follow.
He led me to his room and closed the door. His face was grave.
“They’ve been fussing, Scout.”
Jem and I fussed a great deal these days, but I had never heard of
or seen anyone quarrel with Atticus. It was not a comfortable sight.

Here are a couple others:

...a pronouncement that made me suspect they had been fussing
again.


When Jem an’ I fuss Atticus doesn’t ever just listen to Jem’s side of it

However, there's likely some kind of nuance to fuss that somehow distinguishes it from fight.

He had to, that’s why he was doing it, equaled fewer fights and less fussing.


It's full of southern English, uneducated register.

It's funny because this book is recommended reading material for c2 examination. Seems like they chose this one based on some other reasons than linguistics :)
